# VSCode Playwright Tests show they are debugging but nothing happens

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, playwright

I was debugging tests fine this morning, had a forced reboot, and now all of a sudden when trying to debug nothing appears to be happen (even though it looks like it's debugging). This has happened before, but always seems to resolve itself, with no luck so far this time.

I'm able to debug in a different repo just fine. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Playwright Test for VSCode multiple times with no luck. Any help would be appreciated. See screenshots for the "appearance of debugging", but nothing happening.

The only outputs I can find that may be helpful are:
Angular Language Service:

[Error - 8:23:08 AM] No config file for "file path here" (This is the file containing the test I'm trying to run).

-I have a feeling it has something to do with this since it's an error, but I've changed nothing to any configs since it was debugging fine this morning.  I'm also unaware of any configs for this (and other) test file(s) specifically besides the default playwright config.

Edit: I've checked the other repos I can debug without issue, and they show the same error for no config file, so maybe this isn't the problem

Git (This is outputting about every 1-2 seconds):

2023-03-07 08:34:34.020 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [1097ms]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this could be an issue with the latest version (1.0.8) of the Playwright Test for VSCode extension.  After downgrading to the previous version, 1.0.7, I'm now able to debug again.